# All columns in a data frame Row which is not Nan

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 5000 rows and 400 columns. In each row most of the cells are NaN. For each row I would like to find the columns which are not NaN and then take the  these columns in the dataframe to do some processing . Is there a easy way of doing it. The best i could think was

```
data [ i, ! is.nan(data[i,] ) ]
```

for the ith row. But this throws an error.

Comment: Try `apply(data, 1, function(x) x[!is.nan(x)])`

Comment: Yes . And data[rownames(apply(data, 1, function(x) x[!is.nan(x)]))] will give the required dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data[rownames(apply(data, 1, function(x) x[!is.nan(x)]))]

seems to be working fine for my purposes.